# How to convert a stream to BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, uwp, bitmapimage

I am trying to convert MemoryStream to Image by using the following code.

```
  Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
  BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
  await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
```

but it throws an exception in the `SetSourceAsync` method and the exception is

> System.Exception was unhandled by user code
>         HResult=-2003292336
>         Message=The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 
>         0x88982F50)
>         Source=mscorlib
>         StackTrace:
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task 
>         task)
>         at   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotificat
>         ion(Task task)
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>         at ImageEditor_UWP.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext() InnerException:

How can I convert a stream to an image?

Comment: Use a Try/Catch block

Comment: Could you share your source code? I copied your code and it run well https://github.com/haison8x/sample-uwp-bitmapimage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To image:

```
public async static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<BitmapImage> ImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    var image = new BitmapImage();

    try
    {
        var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return image;
}
```

Comment: BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);

            image.Source = bitmap; this is also working for me.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var img = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Currently `Bitmap` class does not exist in UWP windows 10

Comment: This is WinForms, while the question is about UWP.